CMake does not compile asm-files (cross-compile)
We set up our build system with CMake and besides C and C++-files we need to compile asm-files (.s).
We use a tiarmclang-compiler (LTS3.2.0) and thus need to crosscompile.
While everything works for C and C++ I am struggling on how to setup the asm-compilation.
We have a toolchain-file that defines the CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER via find_program() it is exactly this tiarmclang-compiler. The same way we define everything for C and CXX, the archiver, objcopy and so on. It looks like this:
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY) #Skip compiler tests...

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
######## Checking Environment Variables ########
if("$ENV{TI_HOME_DIR}" STREQUAL "")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Please setup the environment variable TI_HOME_DIR, e.g. /home/$(USER)/ti or c:\\ti")
endif()

set(TI_COMPILER_PATH $ENV{TI_HOME_DIR}/ti-cgt-armllvm_3.2.0.LTS)


# Find the compiler, linker and archiver...
find_program(CMAKE_C_COMPILER
            NAMES tiarmclang
            HINTS ${TI_COMPILER_PATH}/bin
)

find_program(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER 
            NAMES tiarmclang
            HINTS ${TI_COMPILER_PATH}/bin
)

find_program(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER
            NAMES tiarmclang
            HINTS ${TI_COMPILER_PATH}/bin
)

find_program(CMAKE_AR
            NAMES tiarmar
            HINTS ${TI_COMPILER_PATH}/bin
)

find_program(CMAKE_ARMCC_LINKER 
            NAMES tiarmclang
            HINTS ${TI_COMPILER_PATH}/bin
)

find_program(CMAKE_ARMCC_AR     
            NAMES tiarmar
            HINTS ${TI_COMPILER_PATH}/bin
)

find_program(CMAKE_ARMCC_SIZE
            NAMES tiarmsize
            HINTS ${TI_COMPILER_PATH}/bin
)

find_program(CMAKE_ARMOBJCOPY
            NAMES tiarmobjcopy
            HINTS ${TI_COMPILER_PATH}/bin
)

find_program(CMAKE_ARMREADELF
            NAMES tiarmreadelf
            HINTS ${TI_COMPILER_PATH}/bin
)
# enable_language(ASM)

if(NOT (CMAKE_C_COMPILER) OR NOT (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER) OR NOT (CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER) OR NOT (CMAKE_ARMCC_LINKER) OR NOT(CMAKE_ARMCC_AR) OR NOT(CMAKE_AR))
    message(FATAL_ERROR "tiarmclang or tiarmar could not be found!")
endif()

# Removes the default compiler options
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "" CACHE STRING "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "" CACHE STRING "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "" CACHE STRING "")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "" CACHE STRING "")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "" CACHE STRING "")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "" CACHE STRING "")
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILE_OBJECT "" CACHE STRING "")
# Sets Custom Variable to identify that we are using TI Clang
set(ADDITIONAL_COMPILER_IDENTIFICATION "TI Clang" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)

With C/C++ files this toolchain works as expected.
I have an object library which contains the asm-files in question. I activated asm there not by the project but by using
enable_language(ASM)

and then use ASM:
set(TI_UTILITY_IMPLEMENTATION_SOURCES
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/TI_UtilityImplementation/TIAbortImpl.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/TI_UtilityImplementation/TIDeviceResetImpl.cpp 
    CACHE INTERNAL "List of all TI Utility platform sources"
    )

set(TI_ASM_SOURCES
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/TI_UtilityImplementation/HwiP_armv7r_handlers_freertos_asm.S
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/TI_UtilityImplementation/HwiP_armv7r_vectors_freertos_asm.S 
    CACHE INTERNAL "List of all TI asm sources")

function(add_ti_implementation TARGET_EXTENSION CONFIG_FILE_DIR LIB1)

    add_library(ti-implementation-${TARGET_EXTENSION} OBJECT
        EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL
        ${TI_UTILITY_IMPLEMENTATION_SOURCES}
        ${TI_ASM_SOURCES}
        ${CONFIG_FILE_DIR}/Config.h
    )


    target_link_libraries(ti-implementation-${TARGET_EXTENSION}
            ${LIB1}
    )

endfunction()

However, CMake complains about variable CMAKE_ASM_COMPILE_OBJECT not defined.
How should I define this variable?
I did not find any documentation about that.
I tried to set CMAKE_ASM_COMPILE_OBJECT to
${CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER} -mcpu=cortex-r5 -c, so cmake phase proceeds without errors. But calling make gives following error:
[100%] Building ASM object xyz/TI_UtilityImplementation/HwiP_armv7r_handlers_freertos_asm.S.obj
cd /home/auser/xyz/mcu1_0 && /home/auser/ti/ti-cgt-armllvm_3.2.0.LTS/bin/tiarmclang -mcpu=cortex-r5 -c 
tiarmclang: error: no input files

It seems cmake does just not pass the mentioned files to the command. How to correctly set the variable?

Generally you don't want foo.S.obj you want foo.obj. Maybe that was in fact created but something else is looking for the incorrectly named foo.S.obj.

@Jester I thought that too, but there is no file in the build-folder at the mentioned location nor anywhere else. The C- and C++-Files are built correctly on the other hand and are located where they should be. I will update with the cmake calls I do.

@Tsyvarev I updated the post, I hope I fulfilled the requirements

A variable like CMAKE__COMPILE_OBJECT is expected to contain a rule (a command line) for perform a compilation for the specific language. See e.g. that answer about how the variable looks like.

BTW, setting a variable to an arbitrary value just for a "shut up" a warning/error is not a good approach in programming. Instead, search documentation/description for that variable, and try to understand the error message. If unsure, then ask specifically about given variable and the error/warning you get. Asking about the error message you got in case of arbitrary setting a variable is not very useful.

@Tsyvarev ok, so I added it according to the compiler manual: set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILE_OBJECT "${CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER} -mcpu=cortex-r5 -c " CACHE STRING "")
unfortunately now the line get's processed but has no input-files:
cd /xyz/mcu1_0 && /home/auser/ti/ti-cgt-armllvm_3.2.0.LTS/bin/tiarmclang -mcpu=cortex-r5 -c 
tiarmclang: error: no input files```
You can see CMake does not add anything to the line. There are just no files. I add the asm.includecache to the post.

@Tsyvarev the link you posted saved me. Thanks!

I have reduced your question post and make it to focus on CMAKE_ASM_COMPILE_OBJECT variable. Note, that on Stack Overflow we tend to NOT add "Edit" parts: a question post is not a reflection of the conversation, but should contain a final statement of the problem. Anyone who curious about previous revisions of a question could look into "revisions" tab.

thanks to the comment of Tsyvarev I got the solution.
The problem was indeed the CMAKE_ASM_COMPILE_OBJECT-variable. Unfortunately there is just no documentation out there what this variable is used for and how you should use it.
Thanks to one link provided: CMake toolchain file for custom toolchain (-c compiler option different meaning)
I found the working solution. There seem to be some "shadow"-variables that substitute to the final object and source-files used (<SOURCE> and <OBJECT>).
So I used it this way
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILE_OBJECT "${CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER} -x assembler -mcpu=cortex-r5 -c <SOURCE> -o <OBJECT>" CACHE STRING "")

and it worked.

There is no reason to specify variable CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILE_OBJECT as a CACHE one. As you could see, the referenced answer doesn't do that.
